# User session mixed up with another user

Tags: php, session, memcached

We are facing very odd session issue since last month where multiple users are getting same session ID. Previously, all should be working fine as we never received complains from user or noticed such thing.

We received complains from some of our users. As per them, their account had suddenly switched to another user account on our website and they had gained access to the another user account.

We don't have any recent update in server or code base which could have caused this issue and we also tried to produce this issue in production with test account but we are not able to reproduce it.

Few point related to this issue:-

1. We are using Memecache to store session and PHP version is `5.3.3`.
2. Traffic on our site is very nominal (not exceeded more than few hundred requests per minute) and so we dont doubt session_id() gets duplicated.
3. Our current cache control header `"no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"` is already informing client to not cache anything. So as per our understanding, it should not be anything related to cache.

**4. As per our debugging, we can see that, somehow session values of User-1 is getting overwritten by the data of User-2. So it looks that, User-2 never see any problem in his account, but User-1 is able to see the account of User-2. Also, we can see that User-2 is consistently active on the service.**

Can anyone help us finding the reason?

Comment: I think you need to figure out how to reproduce it before you come to us for help, or hire someone who can.

Comment: Hunt through the logs if possible for those users affected, there may be a clue there.

Comment: How did you solved this, i am facing the same...

Answer (score 0):

Please be more elaborate about the session variables , means how you are assigning the values and at which point of time you are assigning the values . What we think that in the middle of a process your session variable is getting reset with another record by mistake . But nothing can be said properly right now , please let us have a look at your session variables first .

Comment: Thank you so much to all for giving respond on it.

We are using default PHP session in our website,

In config.php file at top we are start session as like below.
- session_name('MYSESSIONID');
- session_start();

This config.php file is include in each pages and even with AJAX request too.

On Login Page :- Set user information into session variables

On Logout page :- Unset all the sessions and remove cookies from the browser

Comment: Can you put "session_start" before assigning the session name ?

Comment: As per the PHP.net document : http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php --> session_name() must be called before session_start() in order session to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating session_id with your loggedin user_id, concatenate current time_stamp to that session_id. If you are generating normal session id with some random text or numbers, there might be a possibility of mixing up sessions.